# Joystick interface

Tags: microcontroller, analog, dac

I need some advice for my project. I would like to create a joystick interface for
my old Amiga computer. I have an analog joy with HID USB interface, I can read the position datas in
digital format. I need a circuit what could transform the digital position datas
to an analog output what I could connect to the Amiga's analog inputs.

Heres the Amiga joyport pinout:
allpinouts.org/index.php/Mouse/Joystick_Amiga_9_pin

Heres how the Amiga measure the positions:
http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Hardware_Manual_guide/node0184.html
http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Hardware_Manual_guide/node0188.html

So I want to create an interface circuit (this is just a small part of the project)
what can substitute the 470 Kohm potentiometers of the old analog joysticks.

My idea is that I would feed the MCU's DAC (I use an ATXMega128A1U + USB host IC) with the digital
positions, and I would connect the DAC's output to a voltage controlled current generator.

So the analog part is bit unclear to me. I need some idea what would be the best solution.

Comment: Do you have a schematic of the interface circuit as well? Does the input really need to be resistance? I wonder if voltage would be fine? Otherwise could you use a digital potentiometer?

Comment: No sorry, I don't know where to start. Maybe I could, but only if theres no other way. I would like to solve this with the MCU and with a simple or cheap circuit.

Answer (score 1):

An analog joystick is basically a pair of potentiometers wired as variable voltage dividers - just like you'd wire a potentiometer up to the analog input of an Arduino, etc.

So the output is just a variable voltage from 0V to 5V.

You can use a DAC to generate a 0-5V range, which could be controlled through SPI, I2C, etc, or some microcontrollers contain a DAC within them.  Not all can do the full 0-5V range though.

Another option would be to use a digital potentiometer as if it were a real potentiometer in a joystick - it'll just be digitally controlled instead of controlled by hand.

Comment: The MCU's (what I use) DAC max ref voltage can't be higher than the Vcc. (3.3V). But doesn't matter, consider the last link. I need to charge a capacitor, I need to control the charger current, if I understand well. I know the digital potentiometers, but I would like to solve this with the MCU's DAC, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The Amiga joystick input has a digital option, basically a switch for each direction and two buttons. So you can simply wire GPIOs into it.

Comment: Normally, but there's analog mode as well. If you check the joyport's pinout, you can see the paddle pinout mode, in this mode you control the left/right direction with the X potentiometer and the up/down direction with the Y potentiometer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on further digging of the documentation, your voltage-controlled current source (VCCS) sounds like a good option. If I read the following document correctly, the computer determines the controller position by discharging a capacitor, letting it charge, and counting how many horizontal scans of the screen it was above a set charge point.

http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Hardware_Manual_guide/node0186.html

This seems really strange and archaic to me, but the computer appears to be older than I am... I don't know why they aren't just using the pot as a voltage divider and using the ADC to read the voltage. At any rate, if you control how fast that capacitor charges, you should be able to mimic the old controller. Here is the schematic as well:

[image: Schematic]

http://amigadev.elowar.com/read/ADCD_2.1/Hardware_Manual_guide/node02E7.html

You can build a simple VCCS with a DAC, op-amp, and BJT. You'll supply the output of the current source (not sink!) to pin 9 instead of the middle wiper of the pot.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvWIdG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you that you dug a bit to understand the problem. This schematic is promising, I will try to build it on the next week. Which type of transistor would be the good choice as Q1 (eg a BC327) ?

Comment: Yeah, that will probably work.

Comment: If it discharges a capacitor, using PWM outputs from the MCU will do the same trick, with a much simpler hardware implementation. Also, from what I remember, few games used the analog mode.

Comment: Hi
I built this circuit, it works, but... only the DAC's most upper range is usable, but that's not even linear. I use a 12bit DAC, the voltage range is 0 to Vcc (3.3V). From 0xD00 to 0xFFF is okay, when I increment the DAC's data register, the change reflects in the calibrator program on the Amiga. Between 0x600 and 0xC00 the position stagnates or slightly change. And below 0x600 the transistor is totally closed, the position in the calibrator program is invalid.

Comment: How should I modify this circuit, that let it's input range match with the DAC's output range, and let it's output range match with that range what the Amiga expects?

Sorry, my english is poor, but I hope you understand.

Comment: Well the math and the programming is a different issue. You'll have to read through the Amiga documentation and figure out how to map the current from this circuit to represent the timing in the the Amiga software. You'll have a transfer function of sorts to related the two together. The 12 bits of your DAC aren't automatically liberally related to the timing window of the Amiga.